# Proving that the integral of a $2$-form on a surface is independent of the chosen local frame

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I'm having trouble proving that the integral of a $2$-form over a surface does not depend on the chosen frame.

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ and $F_a \colon U_a \to S$, $F_b \colon
U_b \to S$ two parametrizations of the patch $S_a \cap S_b = F(U_a) \cap
F(U_b)$. The $2$-form $\omega$ can be written as $\omega = f_a \mathrm du_{F_a}
\wedge \mathrm dv_{F_b} = f_b \mathrm du_{F_b} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_b}$.

We define the integral of $\omega$ with respect to the local parametrization
$(U_a, F_a)$ as follows:
$$\int_{(U_a, F_a)} \omega = \int_{U_a} f_a \circ F_a\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv$$
I want to prove that if $\operatorname{supp} \omega \subset S_a$ and
$\operatorname{supp} \omega \subset S_b$, then the integrals of $\omega$ over
$(U_a, F_a)$ and $(U_b, F_b)$ are equal.

Let $h_{ba} = F_b^{-1} \circ F_a$ and also $D_a = F_a^{-1}(\operatorname{supp}
\omega)$, $D_b = F_b^{-1}(\operatorname{supp}\omega)$. We (should) have:
$$\begin{align}
    \int_{(U_b, F_b)} \omega &= \int_{U_b} (f_b \circ F_b)\,\mathrm
    du\mathrm dv = \int_{D_b} (f_b \circ F_b)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv =
    \tag{$\star$}\\
    &= \int_{D_a} (f_b \circ F_b) \circ h_{ba}~|\;\!\!\det
    Jh_{ba}|\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv =\\
    &= \int_{D_a} (f_b \circ F_a) \det Jh_{ba}\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv
    \color{red}{\stackrel{??}{=}}
    \int_{D_a} (f_a \circ F_a)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv =\\
    &= \int_{(U_a, F_a)} \omega
\end{align}$$

In $(\star)$ I used the change of variables theorem (Jacobi theorem I think it's called?). I don't know how to bridge the red equals sign. I tinkered with the transformation law for $2$-forms, which is
$$\tilde \omega|_P = \det(Jh_{ba})|_{(u, v)} \omega|_P$$
where $P = F(u, v)$ and $J$ represents the Jacobian matrix. Since in our case
$\tilde\omega$ is $\omega$ with a different local frame we can write
$$f_a(P) \mathrm du_{F_a} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_a} = \omega|_P = \tilde\omega|_P
= f_b(P) \mathrm du_{F_b} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_b} = \det Jh_{ba}|_{(u, v)}
f_a(P) \mathrm du_{F_a} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_a}$$
Moreover $P = F_a(u, v)$, so over $S_a \cap S_b$ the following holds:
$$f_a \mathrm du_{F_a} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_a} = f_a (\det(Jh_{ba}) \circ F_a^{-1}) \mathrm du_{F_a} \wedge \mathrm dv_{F_a}$$

However, I don't see how this helps in the last steps of the proof above. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: First, you need to assume the parametrizations both give the correct orientation. (That takes care of the absolute value issue with the Jacobian.) It really would be better if you wrote $F_a^*\omega = f_a du_{F_a}\wedge dv_{F_a}$. Your having $\omega = \tilde\omega$  and $\tilde\omega = \det(Jh_{ba})\omega$ is obviously a problem. It only makes sense to write $\omega = h_{ba}^*\tilde\omega$ and sort it out from that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the suggestions. My professor defined the pullback but never uses it. I'm trying to get acquainted with it from the Wikipedia article. I don't really understand your notation though. How can we write $F_a^*$ if $F_a$ isn't a map between surfaces?